# Let $f$ be real valued function on $\Bbb R$. Let $g(x,y)＝f(x＋y)-f(x)-f(y)$. Supposed that g is bounded on $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Let $f$ be real valued function on $\Bbb R$.
Let $g(x,y)＝f(x＋y)-f(x)-f(y)$・・・①.
Supposed that g is bounded on $\Bbb R^2$.

Let fix $a∈\Bbb R$, $a_n＝1/2^n f(2^na)$

I would like to prove $｛a_n｝$ is cauchy sequence.

I tried to prove $a_m-a_n →0$,when $m＞n→∞$, but I don't know the timing to use ①.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would ask: have you tried to prove it for $g=0$? In any case, I think this is not true in general even for $g=0$ if you don't assume some continuity or monotonicity

Comment: @LorenzoPompili I think this is true. See my answer!

Comment: You are right XD what I was thinking about is that it doesn't work for, let's say, $a_n＝1/e^n f(e^na)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say $g$ is bounded by $C$. Then you have
$$|f(2x)-2f(x)| \le C$$
for all $x \in \mathbb R$. This gives you
$$|a_{n+1}-a_n| =  \frac{|f(2\cdot 2^n a)-2f(2^n a)|}{2^{n+1}} \le \frac{C}{2^{n+1}}.$$
Now work out what that means for $|a_n-a_m|$ and you are done.

Comment: an＋1-an→0 does not imply am-an→0 in general, but in this case, does that hold?

Comment: @Nekojiru That's why you have to work out $|a_n-a_m|$. It's only one simple step left over.